# Broken boot ubuntu 15.04 - Adding repository from live-usb

Tags: boot, grub2, apt, 15.04, boot-repair

When I installed ubntu 15 I pressed ctrl c and the installation was interrupted. I got the error about `kernel-panic`. I try to do a boot-reapir using a live-cd. I ran it with purge grub as was recommended in some site but I get the error that I need to do `sudo chroot`. After doing it I got the error

`Please enable a repository containing the [grub-efi-amd64-signed] packages in the software sources of Ubuntu 15.04 (sda6). Then try again`

How can I proceed  and add it to my ubuntu repository?